# A Label that only appears for a set period of time

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am trying to create a text label that will only appear on the screen for a few seconds. 
I am wondering if there is a function which does this as on stackoverflow i have only seen ones on other programming languages rather than python python v3.4.2.

Comment: To make something happen in tkinter after a set amount of time, use [`after`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method).

Comment: Searching SO for `[tkinter]'root.after'` will give you several examples of using the .after method.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.after(time, callback)` and `pack_forget` if you used pack methode:

```
import Tkinter


def hide():
    label.pack_forget()

root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("200x50")

v = Tkinter.StringVar()
label = Tkinter.Label(root, textvariable=v)

v.set('some text')
label.pack()

root.after(3000, hide)
root.mainloop()
```

See also `grid_forget` and `palce_forget`.

Comment: what is `e=0` for? You don't use `e` and `e` isn't passed in.

Comment: @V.Bon If you used `label.place()`.